# Problems when comparing layers in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to check if the layer of the object that hits the raycast is player to do something.

I first tried this:

```
if (hit.transform.gameObject.layer == player)
```

where hit is RayCastHit and player is a Layermask

While debugging, I found that this works for some reason:

```
if (hit.transform.gameObject.layer == 8)
```

but this doesn't

```
if (hit.transform.gameObject.layer == player.value)
```

I'm so confused. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layer and LayerMask are different, e.g. You have defined a layer called "Player" at index 8, then you can retrieve this layer with:

```
int layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player");
```

The value of `layer` is `8`.

If you do:

```
LayerMask mask = LayerMask.GetMask("Player");
```

Then you get a [bit mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_mask), its value is `1 << 8`. A layer mask is able to represent multiple layers, it can be used in some methods like [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)